# How to get listview item click count in each row?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have a ListView in which there is a button in each listview item.Whenever user clicks the button in each row,i want to get the click count of button in each row seperatelyWhen i have a counter which increments as user clicks the button.But the count is not seperate for each row.It just increments when any button is clicked irrespective of the row.

Apparently there is an add button in each listview row.When the button is clicked,i want to change each button label with the click count.

Code:

```
list = getListView();
            list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                        final int position, long id) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub



                    TextView add = (TextView) view
                                .findViewById(R.id.btn_add);
                        DishCount = (TextView) view
                                .findViewById(R.id.textDishCount);


                        ((TextView) view
                        .findViewById(R.id.btn_add)).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) 
                            {
                              try
                                {
                                    counter.add(position,counter.get(position)+1);
                                    }

                                catch (Exception e)
                                {
                                    e.printStackTrace(); 
                                    counter.add(position, 1); 
                                    }


                                totalcount= counter.get(position);
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Value is "+totalcount, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                DishCount.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                DishCount.setText(String.valueOf(totalcount));



                            }
                        });

                    }


            });
```

update method:

```
private void updateView(int index){

            View v = list.getChildAt(index - 
                list.getFirstVisiblePosition());

            if(v == null)
               return;

            count++;
            TextView someText = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textDishCount);
            someText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            someText.setText(String.valueOf(count));
        }
```

Adapter class:

```
public class RestaurantSubMenuListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

private final Activity context;

private final ArrayList<Bitmap> dishImagesRounded;
private final String[] DishName;
private final String[] DishDescription;
private final String[] DishPrice;
Integer count;
TextView itemCount;
Typeface tf,tfb;

public RestaurantSubMenuListAdapter(Activity context,ArrayList<Bitmap> dishImagesBitmapArray, String[] dishNameArray,
        String[] dishDescriptionArray, String[] dishPriceArray, Typeface tf, Typeface tfb) 
{
    super(context, R.layout.restaurant_menu_list_item,dishNameArray);

    this.context=context;
    this.dishImagesRounded=dishImagesBitmapArray;
    this.DishName=dishNameArray;
    this.DishDescription=dishDescriptionArray;
    this.DishPrice=dishPriceArray;
    this.tf= tf;
    this.tfb=tfb;
}


@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View v = convertView;
final ViewHolder h;
if(v == null){
    v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.restaurant_menu_list_item, parent,false);
    h = new ViewHolder();
    h.DishName = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textDishName);
    h.DishDescription = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textDishDescription);
    h.DishPrice = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textDishPrice);
    h.AddButton = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.btn_add);

    h.ImageDish = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageDish);
    h.DishCount = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textDishCount);
    h.AddButton = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.btn_add);



    v.setTag(h);
}else
{
   h = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
}

h.DishName.setTypeface(tfb);
h.DishDescription.setTypeface(tf);
h.DishPrice.setTypeface(tfb);
h.AddButton.setTypeface(tf);
h.DishCount.setTypeface(tf);
h.DishName.setText(DishName[position]);
h.DishDescription.setText(DishDescription[position]);
h.DishPrice.setText("$"+DishPrice[position]);
h.ImageDish.setImageBitmap(this.dishImagesRounded.get(position));

h.ImageDish.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        Intent myIntent = new Intent(context,
                ActivitySelectIngredients.class);
        myIntent.putExtra("TableNumber",23);
        context.startActivity(myIntent);


    }
});

/*h.AddButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        String tag = (String)v.getTag();

        Toast.makeText(context, tag, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        h.DishCount.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        notifyDataSetChanged();

        //count++;



    }
});*/

return v;
} 

/** 
 * to stop recycling of listview items
 */
@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return getCount();
}

/** 
 * to stop recycling of listview items
 */
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return position;
}

private static class ViewHolder{
TextView DishName,DishDescription,DishPrice,AddButton,DishCount;
ImageView ImageDish;

}
```

Comment: Add the variable called `count` for each row in datastructure or holder you are using

Comment: Can u please tell me how to do that?I'm a beginner in android.

Comment: Add a view holder for each item in your list view and add a variable count in the ViewHolder class. Set the view holder object as tag to each list item inside the get view method.. When any item is clicked you can parse it to the view holder object by getting the tag. Then increment the count variable.

Comment: @N5. can u please help me ??

Answer (score 0):

you need to make another list or an array and save the counters. you can't have one counter for all the rows

Answer (score 0):

You can use a static ArrayList of custom type and use it to store click count in its respective position.

Below is the code for object that you can use.

```
public class ItemCount {
    int position;
    int count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Add a datastructure : array or arraylist :

   `ArrayList<Integer> count=new ArrayList<Integer>();`
2. Add Count in List inside onClickLister : list.setOnItemClickListener

   ```
   ArrayList<Integer> count = new ArrayList<Integer>();
   try {
       count.add(position, count.get(position) + 1);
   } catch (Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
   ```
3. Get the total count of item at position n :

   `int totalcount= count.get(n);`

Comment: it throws exception at  count.add(position,count.get(position)+1);

Comment: whats the exceptions?

Comment: IndexOutOfBoundsException at count.add(position,count.get(position)+1);

Comment: change above decllartion of arrylist

Comment: i think,the problem is with the arguments inside the add method.When i replaced it with an integer value,its working fine

Comment: Why is this line used ?? count.add(position, 1);

Comment: incase this position is null the count is init to 1

Answer (score 0):

Just make an another arrayList and increment your count of same positions.